# How can I get information from MySQL with Ajax?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

So i am trying to learn Ajax with jQuery, to retrieve some information. At the moment, I have problem to get the information. My code is very simple at the moment, just because I want to learn how it works. This is my HTML code.

```
<h2>Hello world</h2>
<p id="response"></p>
```

My jQuery code:

```
$(function(){
 $('h2').on('click', function() {
   $.ajax({
    url: "ajax.php",
    type: "get",
    datatype: "json",
    success: function(data){
     $.each(data, function(i, key){
      $("#response").html(key['name']) 
     });
    },
    error: function(data){
     console.log("tjohejsan");
   }
   })
 });
});
```

So when I click on h2 it should retrieve data. What I want is to make a call from my database to get information about the users.
So my php code looks like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM moment2";
$result = mysqli_query($db,$sql) or die("Fel vid SQL-fråga");

$array = array();
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
{
    $array[] = $row;
}
echo json_encode($array);
```

At this point, this is where it fails. I don't know really where the problem is. Because I want an associative array.
I would appreciate it if you could assist me, because as I mentioned, I don't really know how to solve it from here.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: I realised I had a typo while writing this. changing data['name'] to key['name']

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple places that you are going to run into trouble with this. Here is a JSFiddle for you to reference with my tips below:

https://jsfiddle.net/MrProvolone/zgw9ymv3/2/

There are a few things to consider...

1). Your returned data needs to be converted using parseJSON(), which is a built in jQuery function.  This will convert your JSON string into a JavaScript object.

2).  When you are looping through your object, you need to include the number (i) that you are trying to access

3).  Because we are making a new object variable, we don't need the "key" designator in your $.each() function call... **so it becomes** $.each(data, function(i){}); **instead of** $.each(data, function(i, key){});

3).  When you are trying to write out your html, you must grab what is already in the container, then add your new html to it, and finally write it all back out to the container.

**Here is a step by step**:

Instead of:

```
success: function(data){
 $.each(data, function(i, key){
  $("#response").html(key['name']) 
 });
}
```

We need to add the parsing (and remove the "key" variable per #3 above) so it becomes this:

```
 success: function(data){
    var parsed = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
    $.each(data, function(i){
       $("#response").html(key['name']);
    });
 }
```

Now we have a new variable to work off of (parsed) so we need to change both the $.each line, and the .html() line to make sure it uses that new variable....

So this:

```
$.each(data, function(i, key){
  $("#response").html(key['name']); 
});
```

Becomes this:

```
$.each(parsed, function(i){
  $("#response").html(parsed['name']); 
 });
```

But that still won't work.  We are looping through the object, so when we try to access a value, we have to specify which element in the object we are trying to get to.  So anywhere in your loop that looks like this:

```
parsed['keyname']
```

becomes this:

```
parsed[i]['keyname']
```

So now we have:

```
$.each(parsed, function(i){
  $("#response").html(parsed[i]['name']); 
 });
```

At this point you should be getting some html in your container.  However, you will notice that you are only getting the value of the last row of your data.  That is because you are overwriting ALL of your html in the container in each loop, instead of adding to what is already there.  We need to make a new variable to fix this.  So this:

```
$.each(parsed, function(i){
  $("#response").html(parsed[i]['name']);
 });
```

Becomes this:

```
$.each(parsed, function(i){
  var oldhtml = $("#response").html();
  $("#response").html(oldhtml + '<br>' + parsed[i]['name']);
 });
```

Now you will see each result, with a html line break between each one.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I appreciated the time and solution on how to solve this. It works now, cheers!

Answer (score 3):

You have issue in the jquery each function. Replace the success function as

```
success: function(data){
     $.each(data, function(i, key){
      $("#response").html(key['name']) 
     });
    },
```

It is because jquery each function has key and value as argument, so only replace "data" by "key" in your this line: `$("#response").html(data['name'])`

Comment: I tried and changed as you wrote. But still, i wont get the information.
I thought it might be something with the code, so I tried putting console.log in the $.each function, but it wont even write in the console.

Comment: I now get the error "Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'length' in {"email":"test@hotmail.com","name":"test","password":"test","created":"2017-02-18 13:01:44"}

Comment: There are couple of things to be determined. Please, first ensure that you are getting data from the database. Put **print_r($result);die;** after **$sql = "SELECT * FROM moment2";
$result = mysqli_query($db,$sql) or die("Fel vid SQL-fråga");** to ensure that getting data from database

Comment: The error is caused by using the `in` operator on a string, although, it is used normally on `objects`

Comment: The **in** operator only works on **objects**. You are using it on a string. Make sure your value is an object before you using $.each. **$.each(JSON.parse(data), ...);**

Answer (score 1):

In your js, on the success callback, you are using the wrong data, and not appending the data retrieved to the html Tag

Here is an essai

```
success: function(data){
    if(typeof data != "object"){
        data = JSON.parse(data);
    }  
    $.each(data, function(i, key){
        $("#response").append(key['name']) 
    });
}
```

Comment: I tried to change my code to looks like yours, but I get this error:  "Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'length' in {"email":"test@hotmail.com","name":"test","password":"test",‌​"created":"2017-02-1‌​8 13:01:44"

Comment: Add `console.log(data)` in your success callback and show us what you do you get

Comment: Cause i assume `data` is a json object, otherwise update `$.each(data, function(i, key){`  to `$.each(JSON.parse(data), function(i, key){`